# Meteor 0.6.1 release with iFrame - cannot call parent.function

Tags: iframe, meteor

```
<a href="#" onclick="parent.test()">Test Method</a>
```

This worked in 0.5.9. Fails in 0.6.1 with error "caught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'test'". test() is defined in a .js file the client folder. In 0.6.1, all code in .js files appear to be wrapped into an anonymous function. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From release 6.0 Meteor wraps the code of each file into a function in order to prevent the global namespace pollution. If you want to share variables across files,  you have to remove "var" from your variable declaration.

If you use coffeescript, use the @ for you variables.